# Google Recaptcha in django and angular

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I installed  recaptcha (work with django rest framework an angularjs) on my site but i don't now how obtain g-recaptcha-response can anyone show example

```
$scope.submit = function() {
         $http.get('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify').success(function (data) {
            $http.post(callbackUrl, $scope.callback).success(function (data) {
               $scope.isFormActive = false;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('Incorrect');
            });

            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('Incorrect');
            });

        };
```

i don't now how set parameters secret key and response for https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get g-recaptcha-response by calling "grecaptcha.getResponse()" this in your javascript
source: [get_recaptcha_response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Django REST framework (DRF) you might want to checkout these packages:

1. https://github.com/Maximilien-R/django-rest-framework-recaptcha
2. https://github.com/motius/django-rest-recaptcha
3. https://github.com/zueve/django-rest-captcha

The first two are implementing a DRF recaptcha serializer field, you can put it into your serializer and it has its own validators making a call to google verify URL. Last one (`django-rest-captcha` package) is implementing a serializer again with its own validators. All packages are on pypi so you can install them using pip.

Frontend integration according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3):

```
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
  <script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         ...
      });
  });
  </script>
```

Below is an example code for BE using `django-rest-framework-recaptcha` package.

Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_recaptcha.fields import ReCaptchaField


class ReCaptchaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    recaptcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

View:

```
class VerifyTokenAPI(views.APIView):
    allowed_methods = ["POST"]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ReCaptchaSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path("/my/api/endpoint/", VerifyTokenAPI.as_view()),
]
```

Basic test call to BE:

```
data = {"recaptcha": "token"}
response = client.post("/my/api/endpoint/", data)
assert response.status_code == 200
```